# Passing a vector of integers to a function by reference

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am reading in a file of integers into a std::vector. This part of the code is working fine. I have checked this by printing out the vector.

Now, I want to pass this vector into a function by reference. I want to pass it by reference so as to allow the function to modify the contents of the vector. Following is my code count_comparison.cpp:

```
#include "count_comparison.h"
#include "quicksort.h"

int main() {

  ...     
  long long int comp_num;
  comp_num = quicksort(A,10000,0,9999);

  ...
}
```

count_comparison.h has the following contents:

```
...
#include <vector>
std::vector <int> A(10000);
...
```

quicksort.h has the following contents:

```
#include <vector>
long long int quicksort(std::vector <int>& A, int n, int l, int r);
```

quicksort.cpp has the following contents:

```
#include "quicksort.h"
long long int quicksort(std::vector <int>& A, int n, int l, int r) {

  long long int num;

  if (n == 1) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    // modify A
    // calculate num and return it
    return num;
  }
}
```

When I compile count_comparison.cpp using g++ (installed on cygwin in windows), I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccNCnqwV.o:count_comparison.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `quicksort(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int, int, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea where I could be going wrong?

Comment: What does your link line look like?

Comment: Show the exact compiler invocation. I guess you're expecting C++ to be Java and the compiler to guess what's to be linked.

Comment: did you link it correctly? how did you invoke `g++`? you should do sth like `g++ -g -o a.out quicksort.cpp count_comparison.cpp`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I was doing: g++ -o compare count_comparison.cpp. Forgot to add quicksort.cpp to the command

Answer (score 3):

I guess you invoked `g++` with `g++ count_comparison.cpp` only, which means that the implementation of `quicksort` is not provided.

Long story short, try to invoke `g++ -g -o a.out quicksort.cpp count_compaison.cpp` and see if everything works fine.

Now the long story. In c++, `.cpp` files can be compiled individually so that update in any particular file does not lead to building the whole project from scratch. It's a commonly adopted approach to write implementations in `.cpp` files, but each `.cpp` file should be *compiled separately* before linking. When using IDEs, usually a project configuration file tells the IDE to get things straight. However, if you are doing this via commandline tools, you should compile each `.cpp` and *link* them. A handy approach, although not very elegant, is to invoke `g++` and let it decide on whether the input files are for compilation or linking before it invoking other utilities.

Generally speaking, when dealing with larger projects, you should try `g++ -c a.o a.cpp` then finally `ld *.o` to get an executable file.